# Cannot convert string to float in pandas (ValueError)

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe, numeric

I have a dataframe created form a JSON output that looks like this:

```
        Total Revenue    Average Revenue    Purchase count    Rate
Date    
Monday  1,304.40 CA$     20.07 CA$          2,345             1.54 %
```

The value stored are received as string from the JSON. I am trying to:

1) Remove all characters in the entry (ex: CA$ or %)
2) convert rate and revenue columns to float
3) Convert count columns as int

I tried to do the following:

```
df[column] = (df[column].str.split()).apply(lambda x: float(x[0]))
```

It works fine except when I have a value with a coma (ex: 1,465 won't work whereas 143 would).

I tried to use several function to replace the "," by "", etc. Nothing worked so far. I always receive the following error:

> ValueError: could not convert string to float: '1,304.40'

Answer (score 18):

These strings have commas as thousands separators so you will have to remove them before the call to `float`:

```
df[column] = (df[column].str.split()).apply(lambda x: float(x[0].replace(',', '')))
```

This can be simplified a bit by moving `split` inside the `lambda`:

```
df[column] = df[column].apply(lambda x: float(x.split()[0].replace(',', '')))
```

Answer (score 4):

Another solution with `list` comprehension, if need apply `string` [functions](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/text.html#method-summary) working only with `Series` (columns of `DataFrame`) like [`str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html) and [`str.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.replace.html):

```
df = pd.concat([df[col].str.split()
                       .str[0]
                       .str.replace(',','').astype(float) for col in df], axis=1)

#if need convert column Purchase count to int
df['Purchase count'] = df['Purchase count'].astype(int)
print (df)
         Total Revenue  Average Revenue  Purchase count  Rate
Date                                                        
Monday         1304.4            20.07            2345  1.54
```

Answer (score 1):

I have also faced that problem and my problem was resolved using the code below:

```py
import pandas as pd
df['Purchase count'] = pd.to_numeric(df['Purchase count'], errors='coerce')
print(df.dtypes)
```

Answer (score 0):

the below solution worked for me..!!

```
import pandas as pd


df['Purchase count'] = df['Purchase count'].replace(',', '', regex=True).astype(float)

print('type:    ', type(df['Purchase count']))
```