# ValueError: could not convert string to float: '' Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, jupyter-notebook

I got an error in my code while converting string to character.

This is my dataframe image:

[image: Photo]

This how I remove the unit in the data:

[image: Photo]

and then while converting with:

```
for i in ['Power']:
    data[i] = data[i].astype(float)
```

I got the following error message:

[image: Error message]

Comment: Fun fact: if you google your title, you'll get a link to identical question with answers.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39125665/cannot-convert-string-to-float-in-pandas-valueerror

Comment: You left a space after every number. You should also remove space to convert sting into float.

Comment: i google it, and try the solution but still get that error message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'Power': ['58.6 bhp', '126.2 bhp', '88.7 bhp']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)


df=df.replace({'Power':'[a-z]'},'',regex=True)
```

you can use lambda for row wise operation and convert to "float" as below :

```
df['Power']=df['Power'].apply(lambda row: float(row))
```

[notebook Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HsaUQ.png)